# I want to implement NFT purchasing function in the marketplace based on a substrate node

Tags: substrate-node, uniques

Now I am trying to implement NFT purchasing functionality based on a substrate node.

I got this function from the polkadot js documentation.

```
buyItem(collection: u32, item: u32, bid_price: u128)

    interface: api.tx.uniques.buyItem
    summary: See [Pallet::buy_item].
```

but when I try this function. I got this (the image)

[image]

Of course, the function caller is a buyer.

I hope to get any advice to get this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are two checks in `buy_item` that result in `NoPermission`:

```rust
ensure!(details.owner != buyer, Error::<T, I>::NoPermission);
```

The owner is not allowed to buy the NFT.

```rust
if let Some(only_buyer) = price_info.1 {
    ensure!(only_buyer == buyer, Error::<T, I>::NoPermission);
}
```

There is a `whitelisted_buyer` and only they are allowed to buy the NFT.